# Android: Spinner not working properly on 4.4.x

Tags: android, spinner, custom-arrayadapter

I'm adding a **Spinner** programmatically, using a Custom Array Adapter class (which extends **ArrayAdapter**) and a Custom Layout for my Spinner (which consists of an ImageView and a TextView per row).

Everything works fine, except for *Android Kit Kat*: If I tap on my Spinner, it doesn't show dropdown items, even if it contains right items. I'm debugging on Android 6.x and 7.x: it works without any problems.
If I use Custom Adapter and Layout using an inflated layout (inside XML of my activity), I don't have any problems, but if I add my Spinner programmatically (using an external XML layout), it doesn't work.

Do you know if there are known *compatibility issues* about Spinner/Custom Adapter in Android 4.4.x? (I can add code if it can be useful)

**EDIT**

Partial code inside my Activity:

```
TableLayout container = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
LayoutInflater inflator = this.getLayoutInflater();
//Single row I wish to add programmatically
TableLayout row = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
inflator.inflate(R.layout.internal_layout_to_clone, row);
container.addView(row);
//Acquire Spinner
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)row.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
//[here I use Custom Adapter to populate my Select: values are shown properly]
```

`R.layout.internal_layout_to_clone` is an XML file which contains a TableLayout with several TableRow(s) and one of this rows contains my Spinner.

I don't know if the problem is that I'm nesting TableLayout inside another TableLayout, maybe this is not well-managed in Android 4.4

Comment: Are you using google's compat support libraries?

Comment: Yes, I'm using this: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0

Comment: Update the appcompat library and see. might be because of old version.

Answer (score 0):

I belive the problem is somewhere in the code, if you could upload it i'll have a look. 
By the way I have been using an external library for spinner which made the use of spinners easier and it looks better then the regular one.
https://github.com/ybq/Android-SpinKit

Comment: It seems to be a nice library, I will have a look soon, thanks! I'll add code as soon as possible, thanks for your help

Comment: I just uploaded partial code; I also checked my Custom Adapter and it works when I'm not cloning/acquiring layouts: it works when I acquire elements inside my activity layout and it doesn't work when I try to acquire elements from `R.layout.internal_layout_to clone`

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my issue. I changed the way I use to inflate my external layout from this:

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
LayoutInflater inflator = this.getLayoutInflater();
TableLayout row = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
inflator.inflate(R.layout.internal_layout_to_clone, row);
table.addView(row);
```

to this:

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
TableLayout row = (TableLayout)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.internal_layout_to_clone, null);
table.addView(row);
```

I don't know why, maybe some involved methods are not fully compatible with old Android version, but now it works properly on every version tested.

Thanks